# How do I add a suffix (or prefix) elements of an existing list?

Tags: r

Let's say I have an existing list called `myList`.

```
myList <- list(list1=c("item1", "item2"), list2=c("item3", "item4"))
```

`myList` thus contains:

```
$list1
[1] "item1" "item2"

$list2
[1] "item3" "item4"
```

I want to append `.t0` to each element of `list1` and `list2` within `myList` so I end up with:

```
$list1
[1] "item1.t0" "item2.t0"

$list2
[1] "item3.t0" "item4.t0"
```

I do **not** want to go back to the `list(list1=c("item1", "item2"), list2=c("item3", "item4"))` step and add `.t0` there. I want to manipulate `myList` to add `.t0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `lapply` and `paste0`

```
> lapply(myList, paste0, ".t0")
$list1
[1] "item1.t0" "item2.t0"

$list2
[1] "item3.t0" "item4.t0"
```

Answer (score 4):

An implementation with `purrr` from [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org):

Prefix:

```
library(purrr)
nms <- purrr::map_chr(myList, ~ paste0("t0.", .))
```

Suffix:

```
library(purrr)
nms <- purrr::map_chr(myList, paste0, ".t0")
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add an answer if you have a column in `dataframe` format since the other answers don't work for that situation as written.

```
library(tidyverse)
myList <- data_frame(list1=c("item1", "item2"), list2=c("item3", "item4"))
myList <- myList %>% 
  mutate(
    list1 = paste0(list1, ".t0"),
    list2 = paste0(list2, ".t0")
  )
```

This is best if you only have a few columns. You could likely use `map` to iterate through multiple columns.